# How to Wait Until a MongoDB Connection is Made before Using the Database

Tags: javascript, mongodb, async-await

I have the following code to create a connection to my MongoDB database, and to store it for future use.

```
const mongodb = require('mongodb');
const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

// The database will be defined once a connection to between the cluster and mongodb is created
let _database;

const uri = '';
const databaseName = 'db';

const mongoConnect = () => {
    MongoClient.connect(uri)
        .then((client) => {
            _database = client.db(databaseName);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
            throw err;
        });
};

const getDb = () => {
    if (_database) {
        return _database;
    }
    throw 'No database found!';
};

module.exports = {
    mongoConnect,
    getDb
}
```

My problem is that _database is undefined until the connection is made. If my website tries to use the database before _database is defined it will throw an error and crash.

I want to make it so instead of crashing, other portions of my code would just wait until _database is not undefined. Sounds like a await/async solution is needed, but I can't wrap my head around how to approach implementing something like that here. Any advice would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First approach: To make mongoConnect an async function and await on it before any of the remaining code is executed.

```
const mongoConnect = async () => {
    try {
        const client = await MongoClient.connect(uri);
        _database = client.db(databaseName);
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(err);
        throw err;
    }
};
```

In the beginning of your code

```
await mongoConnect();
//Remaning code here
```

Second approach: To make getDb function await till database connection is available

```
const mongodb = require('mongodb');
const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

const uri = '';
const databaseName = 'db';

const databasePromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    MongoClient.connect(uri)
    .then((client) => {
        resolve(client.db(databaseName));
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        reject(err);
    });
})

const getDb = async () => {
    return await databasePromise;
};

module.exports = {
    getDb
}
```

Sample code for you to run and check the second approach:

```js
const databasePromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
    console.log("Connecting to db in 5 seconds...")
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("Done")
        resolve("done")
    }, 5000)
})

const getDb = async () => {
    return await databasePromise;
};

console.time("First_getDb_call")
getDb().then(res => {
    console.timeEnd("First_getDb_call")
    console.log(res)
    console.time("Second_getDb_call")
    getDb().then(res => {
        console.timeEnd("Second_getDb_call")
        console.log(res)
    })
})
```

Comment: For the second approach, wouldn't calling getDb() make it so databasePromise has to run every time I want to use the database? Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @CobaltGecko No, the actual code will run only once. After the first run the promise would be in resolved state and it would just simply return the result that it has.

Comment: This does not works. Unless you use many connections per app. Although exists a issue if u executes await as top level, and if you dont use it, you will have troubles of carrer conditions

Answer (score 0):

**Pretty Simple approach ** Just add await before MongoClient.connect function and make function async Now It will wait for the connection to have response then move forward.

```
const mongodb = require('mongodb');
const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

// The database will be defined once a connection to between the cluster 
and mongodb is created
let _database;

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb';
const databaseName = 'db';

const mongoConnect = async () => {
await MongoClient.connect(uri)
    .then((client) => {
        _database = client.db(databaseName);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        throw err;
    });
 };

const getDb = () => { 
  if (_database) {
    return _database;
}
throw 'No database found!'; 
};



module.exports = {
  mongoConnect,
  getDb
}
```